# Is there a Vim "training wheels" plugin for displaying available shortcuts similar to nano

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm a long time user of GUI IDEs like PhpStorm but I see the value in learning a CLI editor like Vim for when tapping into remote servers. I'm learning commands on a need-to-know basis, but I'd like to see common possible keystrokes similar to how the Nano editor does it at the bottom. Is there a Vim plugin to display shortcuts at the bottom of the screen (or something similar)?

Comment: I don't know of any, but have you tried going through `vimtutor`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Great start! I'd love to have a built-in cheat though.

Comment: `:verbose map` will list all user defined mappings, but it doesn't list builtin mappings.  You can get help on what a specific key does by doing `:help {key}`

Comment: That would be difficult because almost every key does something in Vim.

Comment: @Ben: Even worse, many keys do different things in different contexts, and different combinations. Ctrl-O is fundamentally different in insert and command modes, for instance; and `go` has nothing to do with `o`. At any point there's hundreds of things you could do, without even getting into command mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In absence of a plugin that does exactly what you want, you can still do:

```
:h index
```

Comment: Neat! I like that it's broken down by mode.